# Apply a function with 2 arguments to each duplicated value of a df

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column gene that has duplicated values. I want to apply a function to each set of duplicated values that takes the columns baseMean and pvale as an argument.
I.e. taking all the values in "baseMean" and "pvale" with the same value in "gene" and subjecting them to the function. Subsetting the df manually by "gene" is not an option as there are thousands of different values in "gene".
My first idea was to use:

```
library(lancaster) # a function taking two vectors as input
by(df, df$gene, lancaster, c(df$pvale, df$baseMean))
```

Unfortunately, this treats the vector as a single argument to the function, removing the c(...) does not provide a remedy as the last argument is then dropped.
Is there other option to apply a function to the values of the df that are the same in the "gene" column?
Many thanks!

```
>df
     baseMean        pvale      gene
 1:  13.538457 1.673427e-01 AT1G01020
 2:  15.941034 5.639909e-01 AT1G01020
 3:  12.587422 5.706964e-01 AT1G01020
 4:  13.628112 6.002292e-01 AT1G01020
 5:  26.003794 2.075687e-01 AT1G01020
 6:   0.767917 4.298488e-01 AT1G01030
 7: 129.280745 8.218158e-01 AT1G01040
 8: 539.597575 9.186060e-14 AT1G01060
 9:  32.214273 3.166877e-04 AT1G01060
10:  10.970998 6.589592e-02 AT1G01060
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't know what function you have in mind, this is an example that calculates a simple function of 2 vectors (the mean of the first one plus the sum of the second one) which I then apply to the `iris` dataset which has duplicated `Species` values (similar to your genes)

```r
some_function <- function(x, y) {
  mean(x)+sum(y)
} 

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(my_value = some_function(Petal.Length, Petal.Width))
```

Output:

```r
A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    my_value
  <fct>         <dbl>
1 setosa         13.8
2 versicolor     70.6
3 virginica     107.
```